# How to translate "Rochester Catholic Schools" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, ecclesiastical-latin, academic-latin

I need a bit of help with translating the following phrase from English into Latin:

> Rochester Catholic Schools

How would **Rochester Catholic Schools** be properly translated into Latin?

Answer (score 8):

The most general words for 'school' are *ludus* and *schola*, the latter usually being reserved for more advanced students. (You might also like *academia*, but it really refers to a place for philosophical discussion, rather than instruction.)

There is a choice of adjectival name for Rochester : *Durobrivensis* (from the oldest name, something like 'Durobrivae'), or *Roffensis* (more modern). The latter derives from an old corrupted version of a name that arose before the time of Bede, although there isn't any evidence of a Roman fort to justify the *-c(h)ester* ending.

The choice, then, is between *Ludi Catholici Durobrivenses*, *Scholae Catholicae Durobrivenses*, or the same pair but using *Roffenses* for *Durobrivenses*.

Comment: In between Durobrivae and Roffensis was Hrofescester, which could be used.

Comment: @cmw — the bishop of Rochester signs as 'James Roffensis'. He is not Roman Catholic, but Anglican, which I should, perhaps, have pointed out.

Comment: Roman Catholic Diocese of Rochester [(Dioecesis Roffensis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Catholic_Diocese_of_Rochester)

Comment: @Ken Graham  Oh dear! I think you ought to look at this: http://www.anglicancommunion.org/structures/member-churches/member-church/diocese.aspx?church=england&dio=rochester

Comment: I think *scholae* is must better than *ludi* in this context: see the [*Codex Iuris Canonici*](http://www.codex-iuris-canonici.de/liber3.htm). The term "Catholic schools" almost always includes K-12, at least in the US, and *ludus* evokes grade school and below.

Answer (score 3):

The "Catholic Schools" portion of the phrase could be translated as *Catholicae scholae*.

However, there isn't a specific word for Rochester in Latin, so you may want to check out this article on [Latinisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latinisation_of_names) for a quick overview.
In this situation, the Latin word for Rochester would have to go into either the **genitive** if you want the phrase to mean "Catholic schools of Rochester" or **locative** if you want the phrase to mean "Catholic schools in Rochester". However, we would first need to get over the hurdle of Latinising the proper noun "Rochester". Does anyone else have more experience with Latinising words?

Answer (score 2):

Rochester is also a diocese, and so the Catholic schools would be part of Rochester as a diocese rather than as a city (the diocese will encompass more communities than the actual city). All dioceses have an official Latin name given by the Vatican when they are erected (established). Rochester's is *Dioecesis Roffensis* ([see the reference](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/droch.html)).

*Roffensis* is genitive ("Diocese of Rochester"), so "Catholic Schools of Rochester" (which is what the phrase means structurally as Latin does not use nouns as adjectives like we can in English) would be *Scholae Catholicae Roffensis*.

Comment: Actually, *Roffensis* is an adjective and the town is *Roffa, -ae*: compare to *Archidioecesis Neo-Eboracensis* (not Neo-Eboracae) or *Universitas Oxoniensis* (not *Oxoniae*).

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for the answer! This is valuable insight, but there is a little grammar error. As @brianpck mentions, *Roffensis* is an adjective. For use with *scholae*, it should be in feminine plural nominative: *Roffenses*.

Comment: Are we all at cross purposes here? Being English, I simply (and lazily, I suppose) assumed that the place was Rochester in the UK. Now it seems that the questioner may have been referring to Rochester NY, which seems to be a Catholic diocese. If that's right, I suggest Scholae Catholicae Roffae (not really genitive, but locative, which is identical in form).

Comment: Interesting. I assumed it was genitive because I already knew the Archdiocese of Los Angeles is _Archidioecesis Angelorum in California_, which translates literally as "Archdiocese of the Angels."

Comment: Hey all, thanks so much for the feedback. The Rochester I'm referring to is in Rochester, Minnesota (which was named after Rochester, NY....go figure)  - Would you agree 'Roffenses' is the proper word choice for Rochester?